# How to remove a fragment from url with perl

Tags: perl

I have a url https://nasheidp.com/app/dynamicvalue/exkkilism6wisasas/sso/saml and i want to remove the dynamicvalue from the url and the result should be

> https://nasheidp.com/app/exkkilism6wisasas/sso/saml

The value after app/ and before /exkkilism6wisasas  is completely dynamic.

I am trying something like this

```
use URI ();

$u1 = URI->new("https://nasheidp.com/app/dynamicvalue/exkkilism6wisasas/sso/saml");
$u1->path("thereplacedwith");
print $u1;
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. And simple: `s{/testapp/}{/}`. Have you even tried?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the testapp is dynamic

Comment: @SteffenUllrich updated the question

Comment: but your attempt is still missing which makes it a bad question due to "i have this, i want this, do it for me" nature

Comment: Still simple:  `s{(/app/)(.*/)(exkkilism6wisasas/sso/saml)}{$1$3}`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich exkkilism6wisasas is also dynamic

Comment: @Either i am trying with the URI package provided by perl

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem in multiple ways, however I guess the "easiest" way to approach this would be using regular expressions.

Since your url is a string you can search for the dynamic value and it with an empty string. Searching and replacing something in Perl (can be read upon [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick#Search-and-replace)) is done using `s/valueToBeReplaced/replacedValue/` where `valueToBeReplaced` can be a string value or a regular expression, `replacedValue` can be a normal string (and other values but for your case this doesn't matter).

For your case you probably want to look for the `/app/dynamicValue/sso` part and replace it with `/app/sso`. As `/` is a "metacharacters" (also known as reserved characters) you will need to escape it with a `\`.

This is what you will probably end up with:

```perl
$url = "https://nasheidp.com/app/dynamicvalue/exkkilism6wisasas/sso/saml";
$url =~ s/<pattern>/\/app\/sso/;
```

For the `<pattern>` part you need to find a regular expression that can match the dynamic part.